# Compiler error in using Zbar SDK(library) in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6.1.1

I got the following error while building my project:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZBarCaptureReader", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ZBarViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)  .

I have tried all kinds of solutions form Google but I'm unable to solve it.

[image: Screen Shot Attached]

Comment: You might want to upgrade to 6.3.1 if possible. Also, which architectures are you supporting in your project? Try removing i386 (which is the slice for the simulator) as the ZBar does not need that support (it will not work in the simulator anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Always ,missing some framework or .m file will occur this kind of problem. You should add .m files manually. 
TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class(may be ZBarCaptureReader.m file in your situation) ->Build and Run